# PHP PDO - getting values from the same multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two the same databases:

Table `test1` in database `name_A`:

```
| ID  |   NAME   |    NUMBER    |
|  2  |   test1  |  666555444   |
|  3  |   test2  |  888777444   |
|  4  |   test3  |  666555444   |
```

Table `test2` in database `name_B`:

```
| ID  |   NAME   |    NUMBER    |
|  2  |   test4  |  333555444   |
|  3  |   test5  |  999555777   |
|  4  |   test6  |  222555888   |
```

Table `test3` in database `name_C`:

```
| ID  |   NAME   |    NUMBER    |
|  2  |   test7  |  777555333   |
|  3  |   test8  |  333555111   |
|  4  |   test9  |  159222555   |
```

And I want create three connections to database and search by `number` column in every database and get the biggest number.

Standard query:

```
SELECT * FROM name_A.test1 ORDER BY number DESC
```

But how to "compare" three the same databases? I want to get the biggest `number` based on all these databases and as result I want to get also database name, which contain the biggest number.

Host is the same, difference is into username, password and database name.

Thanks.

Comment: Are all databases on the same server?

Comment: @NigelRen yes, the same server.

Comment: why do you have three databases in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be a limit query, which even avoids the need for an explicit subquery:

```
SELECT NUMBER, 'name_A' AS name FROM name_A.test1 UNION ALL
SELECT NUMBER, 'name_B' FROM name_B.test2         UNION ALL
SELECT NUMBER, 'name_C' FROM name_C.test3
ORDER BY NUMBER DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I don't have any fix, other than to execute the above query with a user having read access to all 3 databases.